# What is the correct ARIA tag for HTML5 number fields

Tags: html, wai-aria

I know that for text fields you can use the ARIA tag role="textbox" but what about the HTML5 number field?

Answer (score 1):

From what I read at http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html, the role appears to be `role=spinbutton`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HTML5 specification: The [`number` state](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29) has the [`spinbutton` role](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#index-aria-spinbutton) by default (implicitly).

[HTML5 recommends *not* to set this role explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952106/1591669).