# In a React component, do <button> tags have any benefits living inside a <form> tag or living outside the <form> tag?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm wondering if there are any advantages to the  tag if I'll be wiring in my button as type="button".

I've tried inside and outside the  tag but don't see any advantages to having a  tag.

```
    <div className="form">
      <form>
        <h4>Desired Username: </h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="uName"
          value={this.state.uName}
          onChange={this.userInput}
          placeholder="Desired Username"
        />
        <h4>Password: </h4>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="pass"
          value={this.state.pass}
          onChange={this.userInput}
          placeholder="Type Password Here"
        />
        <h4>Password Confirm: </h4>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="passConf"
          value={this.state.passConf}
          onChange={this.userInput}
          placeholder="Retype Your Password"
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="button">Register User</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: There were a few subtle differences with the button being inside a form.
1. If <form action="/Register" type="submit">, the button would inherit the type and submit the form.
2. If <form> was used as just a tag, the button would default to being type="button".
3. If <form action="/Register" type="submit"> and <button type="button">, button would be a button.

Answer (score 1):

When type="button" , The button will work as a normal button, Which will be same if you put it inside the form or outside.

But form is something you submit to the server, So in that case you must have type="submit" , And the button must be inside the form, Because if you give type="submit" and put the button outside the form then you are not submitting anything.

Hope this clears your doubt

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not related only to react, there is a similar question about it here:
[Do I need role="button" on a <button>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934719/do-i-need-role-button-on-a-button)

The answer is that the button type is button by default, so there it doesn't matter if you add this type to your button

You should also take a look in [the docs - on the form section](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and understand the "react way" to use a form - it's little different from the regular use of form and the role of buttons is different.

I recommended reading [this article](https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/) that cover the subject of buttons in regular form very well.

Comment: `role` and `type` are different things.

Comment: @apokryfos - sure "Adding role="button" will make an element appear as a button control to a screen reader", but the question that i linked to is talking about role and type

Answer (score 0):

**The usual method to submit forms is keeping the button tag inside the form.**

If the button is inside the form tag you have to give it the type submit and on the form tag include the onSubmit event with a function to be called when the button is clicked.

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
//Input fields
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you prefer to keep the button outside the form tag you will have to put an onClick 
event on the button and take the input values via state.

```
<form>
//Input fields
</form>
<button onClick={this.onClick}>Submit form details</button>
```

One of the main difference between the two is that the 'enter' key being hit is considered as an onsubmit but when an onclick is used it may not be considered as an onclick.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it doesn't actually answer the question why to go with one or the other

Comment: One of the main difference between the two is that the 'enter' key being hit is considered as an onsubmit but when an onclick is used it may not be considered as an onclick.