# How does button surrounded with <p><a> and <button> differes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bootcamp sample html file suggests a button written like this:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="run_update()" role="button">Button</a></p>
```

Though, I've written button always like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="run_update()">Button</button>
```

They seems identical and functions similarly. I'm wondering are they any different or will they impact performance everso slighly?

Comment: Since you’re only executing an action in JS on click, using an anchor for this is semantically incorrect. Also, inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: They are functionally the same and won't affect performance between the 2. The classes are slightly different (see bootstrap documentation) and the role="button" is for accesability - but isn't needed because the default role for button is 'button' https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952106/1772933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For this, always go for `.addEventListener()` instead of `onclick`. `onclick` is not recommended for executing an action in JS.**

###### MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)

 also states that `.addEventListener` must be used instead of `onclick`.

For the button, it doesn't affect the overall meaning and work of it. [A button doesn't cause a change when inside a `p` tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element)

Comment: thanks, i didn't know that and always used onclick